# How to handle collisions in a 2d console game

Tags: c++, oop

I'm making a simple console game using windows.h library. Class Game has a map, which is an array of type CHAR_INFO (structure of unicode symbol and its color). This class also has an array of `Enemy` and `Projectile` objects. Every iteration game updates the position of each object in the game using `Entity`'s method called `move()`, which calculates the next position of an entity and checks if there is a symbol which represents an enemy or a projectile. If there is, method `move()` calls one of these functions:

```
    virtual bool onProjectileCollision() = 0;           //collision methods return 0 if the entity is dead
    virtual bool onEnemyCollision() = 0;
```

these functions are overriden by `Enemy` and `Projectile` classes like this:

```
bool onProjectileCollision() override {
        return 1;
    };
bool onEnemyCollision() override {
        return 1;
    };
```

The problem is that I don't know which object the entity collides with (I know only its class), therefore i can't call any method  of this object:

```
class Enemy : public Entity {
int hp;
public:
void die() {
    hp = 0;
}
bool onProjectileCollision() override {
        die();                                             //I can do this
        return 1;
    };
}

class Projectile : public Entity {
public:
bool onEnemyCollision() override {
        enemy.die();                                 // but I can't do this
        return 0;
    };
}
```

How should i build a connection between these objects ?

Comment: You've discovered that it's not sufficient to store just the symbols on the map; you need to also store pointers to objects those symbols represent. Update your design accordingly.

Comment: In order to find the object you are colliding with, you can either (1) search the entire list of objects in the game until you find an object at the desired coordinates, or (2) make every map tile contain or point to a list of all entities in that map tile, so that you only have to search that list. When your game has a large number of objects, option #2 is much more efficient.